# My SOAP request is failing to authenticate using KROLL CORP API can anyone please suggest reasons why this may be

Tags: xml, api, soap, wsdl

Here is my request and response code below using Postman.I cannot figure out why the authentication is returning a failed response.

`Here is my request made with Postman`

```
 POST /OrderStatus/Kroll.Dealer.OrderStatus.svc/Basic HTTP/1.1 
 Host: api.krollcorp.com 
 Content-Type: text/xm
 SoapAction:http://tempuri.org/IOrderStatusService/GetAllOpenOrders 
 ApiKey: myAPIkey 
 User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2 
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Postman-Token: PostmanToken
 Host: api.krollcorp.com 
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
 Content-Length: 620
 Connection:keep-alive 
 cache-control: no-cache

<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Body>
    <GetAllOpenOrders xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <request>
        <DealerAccountNumber xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Kroll.Dealer.EBusiness">mydealeraccountnuber</DealerAccountNumber>
        <Password xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Kroll.Dealer.EBusiness"> mypassword</Password>
        <UserId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Kroll.Dealer.EBusiness"> myuserid</UserId>
      </request>
    </GetAllOpenOrders>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

`Here is the response`

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetAllOpenOrdersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetAllOpenOrdersResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Kroll.Dealer.EBusiness" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:AuthenticationFailed>true</a:AuthenticationFailed>
        <a:DealerAccountNumber i:nil="true"/>
        <a:Orders/>
      </GetAllOpenOrdersResult>
    </GetAllOpenOrdersResponse>
  </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

I would like to receive a valid authenticated response.

Comment: Content-Type was indeed "Content-Type: text/xml" it just got accidentally removed when posting this question and here is the WSDL https://api.krollcorp.com/OrderStatus/Kroll.Dealer.OrderStatus.svc/Docs?singleWsdl